# Remove a fragment which is not put to stack in my case

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-fragments

Suppose I have two fragments: `firstFragment`, and `secondFragment`

I know I can replace a fragment by:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_placeholder, firstFragment);
fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Like the above code shows, I did not add the above `firstFragment` to **back stack**.

Then, I replace with the `secondFragment`, But this time, I add the `secondFragment` to **back stack**:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_placeholder, secondFragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null); //add to back stack
fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

On my mobile screen, it is now showing the `secondFragment`.

My question is, how can I remove the `firstFragment` which is **not** added to **back stack** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After detaching the fragment the fragment will be destroyed. To make sure wether your fragment is still in the layout you can use the "Hierarchy Viewer" perspective. To use the hierarchy viewer you have to use an emulator or a rooted device though.  (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html#Creating)

However if you use the android-support-v4.jar to support 1.6 and higher make sure you don't define any fragments in a xml-layout. The fragments in the xml-layout can't be removed when you use android-support-v4.jar. Just do it, if you use fragments which will be displayed all the time (e.g. navigation)

Edit: Replace should remove the firstfragment as well. Replace will replace all children inside the container with the given fragment.

Answer (score 1):

you can [detach](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#detach%28android.app.Fragment%29) the first fragment from the ui. see the doc for more reference

or you can try   [remove](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#remove%28android.app.Fragment%29)

EDIT: standing at the doc:

> If you do not call addToBackStack() when you perform a transaction that removes a fragment, then that fragment is destroyed when the transaction is committed and the user cannot navigate back to it.

So  what you need, I think, is to call remove.

Comment: Does detach mean to remove the fragment from memory or just hide it?

Comment: I think it will hide.. I think it is more like adding it to the backstack

Comment: on fragmenttransaction you have the remove method too